# Responsive: How to float:left li with centrally aligned ul?

Tags: css, position, responsive-design

This is my first attempt at responsive design, so I'm keeping it simple.

I have a `<ul>` which is centrally aligned, with rows of 3 images. However, if the last row has only 1 or 2 images, the entire row is centrally aligned, and I wish to align the images to the left (so they are vertically aligned with the ones on top).

This would be easilly accomplished with `float:left`. However, I want the number of images on each row to adapt to the window size, while keeping the `<ul>` centered on screen.

Here's a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Cthulhu/gQBpU/2/) with only one item on the bottom row, which is centered. If you resize the window so it becomes smaller, the number or items on each row will adapt and the list will remain centered on screen, but the last row will still be centered. Is there any way I can align the last row to the left?

**EDIT:** Here's some pictures, as requested. This is what I'm looking for: 
the `<ul>` is **centered** on screen, but the bottom row is aligned to the left.

[image]

However, if we resize the window, the list will adapt, but the `<ul>` is still **centered** on screen, and the bottom row is still aligned to the left.

[image]

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: would you provide image you want to do

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally I would suggest giving the ul a fixed width and margin: 0 auto; to center, however if you want it to expand with the page, then just give it some fixed left and right margins.

http://jsfiddle.net/gQBpU/13/

```
ul {
    max-width:800px;
    margin: 0 50px;
}

ul li {
    float: left;
}

ul li img {
    margin:5px;
}
```

​

Comment: That way the `<ul>` doesn't keep centrally aligned to the page.

Comment: @Cthulhu, of course it does (use web inspector to see what I mean), but your `<li>` elements are floated left. But just imagine how wonky it would look if you had 5 rows of `<li>` aligned center in the `<ul>` and then the last row was aligned to the left edge of the `<ul>`. You would need javascript to align the last row with the left edge of the row above.

Comment: As long as your `<ul>` has equal right & left margins, it will be centered. And as long as you want your `<li>` elements left-aligned, they will not center in the `<ul>`'s "extra space" without the help of javascript. What you are looking for is an auto-width & centered `<ul>`, but the auto-width logic you are looking for does not exist. You have to make it.

Comment: Ok thanks for the heads up. I was trying to get a CSS-only solution, but I guess I'll have to go for jQuery. I will keep the question open for answers, in case someone comes up with a new idea. If not, you can edit your answer with that info and I will accept it as correct.

Comment: I wish you luck. Honestly, better than employing JS is to decide on a fixed width `<ul>` and center it with auto margins. You'd just have to let go of resizable width. You can still adjust the width per-medium.

Answer (score -1):

If u put all of the images in one `li` and then u do `float: left` then I think it might work.

Comment: and if u want the maximum amount of images in each row to be 3, just do max-width: "width-of-3-image" for li